# Disable embedded media in android Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, ads, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there a way to disable embedded media programatically, like youtube videos, in Chrome Custom Tabs?
My app is being reject because when opening some urls that contain both ads on the web page and a Youtube video, it violates the device and network policy. 
I check on the API and found no way of doing this (like disabling JavaScript e.g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to disable embedded media inside a Custom Tab.